# dcast for numeric and character columns in R - returning length by default

Tags: r, data.table, reshape2, dcast

I have a data which looks like this :-

```
data_source   zip        date        calories      user            price
 compA        45768      18274        3500          abc             912.27
 compB        33098      18274        3500          groups          981.28
 compA        39104      18274        2500          ands            659.75
```

I would like to have wide format of data using dcast; Earlier it use to work, but now it does not.

```
data.table::dcast(zip + date + calories ~ data_source, value.var=c("user","price"), data=data)
```

As you can see the column in `value.var` has `character` and `numeric` value both, and so I'm confused what to use in `fun.aggregate`. So the data converted is defaulting to `length` which is what I do not want. I just want the values as it is but in wide format. Thanks for your help.

Comment: As akrun noted, you will see length used only if there are duplicates by your x ~ y vars. Try `DT[, if (.N > 1) .SD, by=.(zip, date, calories, data_source)]` to see the duplicated rows.

Comment: @frank-2: This was a great help. Thanks . Please keep up the good work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can specify `length` in `fun.aggregate` if the `length` is needed

```
library(data.table)
dcast(setDT(data), zip + date + calories ~ data_source, 
       value.var=c("user","price"), length)
```

---

Based on the data showed, there are no duplicates, so it would work

```
dcast(setDT(data), zip + date + calories ~ data_source, value.var=c("user","price"))
```

If there are duplicates, make a correction to have unique combinations by adding `rowid` for the grouping variable

```
dcast(setDT(data), rowid(zip, date, calories) + zip + date + calories 
          ~ data_source, value.var=c("user","price"))
```

Comment: As I mentioned in the question, this should work :-  `dcast(setDT(data), zip + date + calories ~ data_source, value.var=c("user","price"))` but it doesn't. And I get length which is not what I want . Using `rowid` throws error  `Error in zip + date : non-numeric argument to binary operator`

Comment: @newbie Consider `dcast(setDT(data), rowid(zip, date, calories) + zip + date + calories 
              ~ data_source, value.var=c("user","price"))` this.   Earlier, I had a typo `rowid(zip + data + calories)` instead of `rowid(zip, data, calories)`

Comment: Thanks mate for your help. It works.